# Can my RecyclerView.ViewHolder s be a non-static outer class?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have multiple `View` types in my `RecyclerView`. I understand I need to write multiple `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`s.

I'm trying to write these in a different package to make the whole project organization cleaner.

I know that while using the `ViewHolder` pattern for a ListView, the `ViewHolder`s should(must/can?) be made static inner classes.

Can the `ViewHolder`s for `RecyclerView` and `ListView`be non-static and non-inner and still retain the performance benefit they were intended for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**. It is best practice to create recyclerview adapter using separate **non-static** class for `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. The benefits are:

> - By creating **inner static** class and **separate** , It is reusable in the case of **same** `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` for other adapters.
> - If your using `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in only single adapter, you can declare it into inner class of your adapter.

Talk about **performance** :

As per [GC performance hit for inner class vs. static nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380600/gc-performance-hit-for-inner-class-vs-static-nested-class)  and advantage of recyclerview:

> While using `RecyclerView`, it's recycle the instances viewholder, so the memory impact is not a problem. The static one will take less memory than the other one.

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302613/2949612) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302403/2949612) good answer's to get more idea.

I hope it's help's you.